# '<' not supported between instances of 'Post' and 'Post' django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

when i tryed to loop the posts from the list pposts
i get this err

```
**'<' not supported between instances of 'Post' and 'Post'**


TypeError at /
'<' not supported between instances of 'Post' and 'Post'
TypeError at /
'<' not supported between instances of 'Post' and 'Post'

TypeError at /
'<' not supported between instances of 'Post' and 'Post'
TypeError at /
'<' not supported between instances of 'Post' and 'Post'
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ch = [
            ('pvp','pvp'),
            ('Default','Default'),
            ('bedrock','bedrock')
        ]
    xch = [
        ('x1','x1'),
        ('x4','x4'),
        ('x8','x8'),
        ('x16','x16'),
        ('x32','x32'),
        ('x64','x64'),
        ('x128','x128'),
        ('x256','x256'),
        ('x512','x512'),

    ]
    vch = [
        ('1.7','1.7'),
        ('1.8','1.8'),
        ('1.9','1.9'),
        ('1.10','1.10'),
        ('1.11','1.11'),
        ('1.12','1.12'),
        ('1.13','1.13'),
        ('1.14','1.14'),
        ('1.15','1.15'),
        ('1.16','1.16'),
        ('1.17','1.17'),

    ]
    author =  models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, editable=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    mainimage = models.ImageField(null=True ,upload_to='photes')
    image1 = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='inphotes')
    image2 = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='inphotes')
    image3 = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='inphotes')
    file =  models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='files')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    xnumber = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=xch, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ch, null=True)
    discord_id = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')
    
    
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title  + str(self.author)
  
    def save(self, *args, **kawrgs):
        slug = slugify(self.title)
        _2 = 'post'
        has_slug = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
        count = 1
        while has_slug:
            count += 1
            slug = slugify(self.title) + '-' + str(count)
            has_slug = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()

        self.slug = slug
        super().save(*args, **kawrgs)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_added']
    
    def get_absolute_url (self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)})
```

**views.py**

```
def frontpage(request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    #loged in profile 
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user= request.user)
    #check who we are following
    users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
    #val
    pposts = []
    qs = None
    #get the posts pepole we follow
    for u in users:
        p= Profile.objects.get(user=u)
        p_posts = p.post_set.all()
        pposts.append(p_posts)
    
    #my posts
    mposts = []
    my_posts = profile.profiles_posts()
    mposts.append(my_posts)
    if len(pposts) > 0:
        qs = sorted(chain(*pposts), reverse=True)
    return render(request, 'posts/frontpage.html', {'posts': qs, 'pposts': qs })
```

and i dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not on your loop but on the `sorted()` function. This function require a way to compare two objects of your iterable. By default, it uses the `<` operator, and if it is not implemented for your objects, it throws an error. You must use `sorted` like this :

`sorted(ppost, key=aFunctionThatTakesTwoObjectsAndReturnABoolean)`

Comment: i just add a key `key= lambda x: x.date_added` and it work

Comment: @7mood if so please consider to mark this answer as accepted to close the question